# ng-repeat deosn't the data from JSON object in the HTML Template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to render a json as a table in a HTML Template using angularjs ng-repeat element. The script file passes the JSON object, but the ng-repeat wont render the contents of JSON.

I followed the steps from this tutorial link.

https://codepen.io/salva341/pen/aYKmvG

html template section where ng-repeat doesn't render properly

```
<div ng-controller="WorkflowShowCntrl">
   <table class="table striped">
     <thead>
        <th>Job Name</th>
        <th>Job Id</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr  ng-repeat="ttm in records.response" >
            <td>{{ttm.name}} </td>
            <td>{{ttm.status}} </td>
            <td>{{ttm.name}} </td>
            <td>{{ttm.name}} </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table> 
</div>
```

app.js
angularjs 1.6.6

```
$http.get("/api/data-depot/currentjob/list")
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.records = {"response":response.data}
    $scope.parseItem = function(string)
    {
        var newString = string.replace(/['\']/g,'');
        var jsonFormated = JSON.parse(newString);
        return jsonFormated.Message;
    }
});
```

Google chrome inspector : Section inspection screenshot
I have used an angularjs add-on inspector for chrome.

[image]

Comment: ttm is an array , you should maybe pass records.response as data then make an ng-repeat="ttm in data"

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did as you suggested. Still the data doesn't appear within in the <td> tag. I checked the inspector, ng-repeat = "ttm in data" still holds the data but doesn't appear on the template.

Comment: The line `$scope.records = {"response":response.data}` makes for confusing code. Using `$scope.records = {"data": response.data}` would be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like ttm is the array you want to display for.  So I believe your ng-repeat should be more like:

```
    <tr  ng-repeat="record in ttm" >
        <td>{{record.name}} </td>
    <td>{{record.status}} </td>
    <td>{{record.name}} </td>
    <td>{{record.name}} </td>
```

ttm being the array, and record being a made-up name for each item in that array.

See: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, your are referencing wrong array name in your HTML binding.

Try this

```
<div ng-controller="WorkflowShowCntrl">
   <table class="table striped">
     <thead>
        <th>Job Name</th>
        <th>Job Id</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr  ng-repeat="item in records.response.ttm" >
            <td>{{item.name}} </td>
            <td>{{item.status}} </td>
            <td>{{item.name}} </td>
            <td>{{item.name}} </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was was able to achieve what I wanted.

I added ng-bind element to display the data on the html template. That is weird. No of the scope variable gets displayed on the html template without ng-bind element. This investigating that is strange this is happening.

I would like to thank @Thaier Alkhateeb for their valuable comment.

Revised code snippet

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in records.response ">
  <tr  ng-repeat="ttm in data">
    <td ng-bind="ttm.name"> </td>
    <td ng-bind="ttm.appId"> </td>
    <td ng-bind="ttm.created"> </td>
    <td ng-bind="ttm.status"> </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```